# Ansible Template with Jinja formatting

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook that runs a few commands on network devices and pulls the results into separate lists, and then using Template + a .j2 file outputs it all into a seperate file. The template looks like:

```
{% for i in ips %}
IP: {{ i }}
{% endfor %}

{% for j in intf %}
Intf: {{ j }}

{% for k in br_list %}
BR: {{ k }}
{% endfor %}
```

My output looks like this:

```
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 127.0.0.2
IP: 127.0.0.3
IP: 127.0.0.4

Intf: Vlan1
Intf: Vlan2
Intf: Vlan3
Intf: Vlan4

BR: False
BR: False
BR: False
BR: False
```

What I want is for the output to be tabulated like this:

```
IP            Intf            BR
127.0.0.1     Vlan1           False
127.0.0.2     Vlan2           False
127.0.0.3     Vlan3           False
127.0.0.4     Vlan4           False
```

Any nested loops I tried returns duplicates of each list. Is this possible with Ansible/Jinja?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [zip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#combination-filters) filter:

```
{% for i in ips | zip(intf, br_list) %}
{{ "%-10s" | format(i[0]) }}{{ "%-10s" | format(i[1]) }}{{ "%-10s" | format(i[2]) }}
{% endfor %}
```

`"%-10s" | format(i[0])` is to get 10 spaces padding on the right side.

You can even use nested loop:

```
{% for i in l1 | zip(l2,l3) %}
{% for j in i %}
{{ "%-10s" | format(j) }}
{%- endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```